# Number of fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am new in salesforce and I have a question. I am creating a new reporty type using opportunites and when I was in field layout properties I noticed there were total 40 fields for opporutiy object. I didnt had another object relation with opportunity just simple opportunity. But when I went to opportunity in in object manager there were only 29 items listed in fields and realtionship. Why are there 11 more fields in opportunity in reprot type then in fields and realtuionship

[image]

[image]

I was expeting the same number of fields in object manager and in report type but report type had more fields even when no object was linked with it

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of fields that exist in the table but aren't visible in setup because you can't modify them, can't change user's right to see/edit them. It's bit like https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_objectfields.htm&type=5 but it doesn't mention CreatedDate, LastmodifiedDate, SystemModStamp... and on Opportunity there are more.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm may be a good start but if you truly want everything - run a "describe" operation [in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) or maybe [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) (https://workbench.developerforce.com/ -> utilities -> rest explorer for example)